# Unable to play Unity web player file embedded in Squarespace page? Will not load?

Tags: c#, web, unity-game-engine, squarespace

Alright, I have built my project for web and have followed several tutorials including this: http://synersteel.com/blog/2015/5/12/unity3d-hosting-a-web-build-on-squarespace-using-dropbox to embed the Unity web player in my squarespace web page.

I have hosted  Unity 3D file in dropbox and changed the link after `u.initPlugin` in my HTML file. I did everything as instructed but when I load my web page I get this: 
[image]

This is frustrating as it will not load (the line will not go across). How can I fix this? I need to share my Unity project publicly with a link by tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Unity **Web Player** has been **discontinued**. It doesn't work on Chrome and other top web browsers anymore. WebGL replaced it.The reason for this is because web browsers removed features/API that that is required to run Unity Web Player games.

Build your Unity project as a WebGL then upload it to your website. This requires Unity 5 and above.

[image]