# Failed to update Unity Web Player

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

When i run my Unity3d Web player html file it always give this error on

- **MAC**.
- **Error Line**
  Failed to update Unity Web Player.

I need solution for run my webplayer build on browser .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37264914/3785314) times since the last 10 hours but the answer still remain the-same.

Unity **Web Player** has been **discontinued**. It doesn't work on Chrome and other top web browsers anymore. WebGL replaced it.The reason for this is because web browsers removed features/API that that is required to run Unity Web Player games.

Build your Unity project as a WebGL then upload it to your website. This requires Unity 5 and above.

[image]

Comment: No But i need not want it to run on Chrome i need it to run on Firefox or Safari and it is running smoothly on some PC's . But it is not running on my PC. It is running some days before but as i update new webPlayer . It gives me this kind of error and i do not get any solution of this till now.                            Please provide me a feasible solution for this problem . I have to run this build for Unity3d Web Player . Thanks In Advance.

Comment: @Flexsin_Unity NPAPI will be killed by Firefox at the end of this year. Unity just discontinued their web player in 5.4 release. They longer update it. Please understand this. You may get it work but sooner or later it won't because it no longer updated. Why can't you use WebGL?

Comment: Yes , i need only this thing that how can i get it work now. I know all the concept of NPAPI but right now i have issue how can i sort out this issue.Please give me response .  Thanks .

Comment: @Flexsin_Unity You failed to answer why you can't you use WebGL.. You said you understood the concept of NPAPI but you are still asking the-same question. Anyways, good luck!

Comment: Because the project i am working is only for Web player and i have to do these thing on web Player.